# Makemigrations in Django

Tags: django

I cannot "makemigrations" in my Django project. When I try to do

```
"python manage.py makemigrations"
```

It shows the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ani/Desktop/Backup/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ani/Desktop/Backup/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ani/Desktop/Backup/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/ani/Desktop/Backup/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ani/Desktop/Backup/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ani/Desktop/Backup/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 89, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
  File "/home/ani/Desktop/Backup/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/ani/Desktop/Backup/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 273, in build_graph
    raise exc
  File "/home/ani/Desktop/Backup/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 247, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "/home/ani/Desktop/Backup/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 243, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/home/ani/Desktop/Backup/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 243, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/home/ani/Desktop/Backup/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 96, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration djoser.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('auth', '0011_update_proxy_permissions')
```

I tried installing mysqlclient and creating the database all over again but then it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? The `'0011_update_proxy_permissions'` migration was added in Django 2.2, so upgrading might fix the problem.

Comment: Also make sure to have `dango.contrib.auth` in your installed apps:

`INSTALLED_APPS = [..., 'django.contrib.auth', 'djoser',...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your migrations directory is broken. Django creates migrations files for each migration (each time you type `makemigration`.

Currently, one of your migrations file has something like:

```
dependencies = [
    ('accounts', '0011_update_proxy_permissions'),
]
```

And `migrations/0011_update_proxy_permissions.py` doesn't exist. You need either edit this migration manually or remove everything in migrations directory and run `makemigrations` from scratch. If you remove migrations you will also need to drop the database so django would create it from the scratch.

There're a lot of articles out there that would help you to investigate your issue further. Like [this](https://realpython.com/django-migrations-a-primer/) one